# Errors in installing keras using pip?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pip, h5py

I am trying to install Keras library using pip in windows 10. I have all the requirements installed, python>=3.8, pip>=20.0.0, NumPy, pandas, matplotlib, virtualenv. But I'm getting the following error.

```
(keras) C:\Users\namba>pip install keras
Collecting keras
  Using cached Keras-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting h5py
  Using cached h5py-3.1.0.tar.gz (371 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\namba\keras\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.19.4)
Collecting pyyaml
  Using cached PyYAML-5.3.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (199 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in c:\users\namba\keras\lib\site-packages (from keras) (1.5.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
  Building wheel for h5py (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\namba\keras\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\namba\keras\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\namba\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0_p1fdyc'
       cwd: C:\Users\namba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k9e6wdb4\h5py
  Complete output (70 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\h5py_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\ipy_completer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\dims.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\files.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\selections2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attribute_create.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attrs_data.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_big_endian_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_completions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_getitem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_swmr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dimension_scales.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dtype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file_image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5f.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5p.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5pl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5t.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_objects.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_slicing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_highlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_virtual_source.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  running build_ext
  Loading library to get version: hdf5.dll
  error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly
  error: Could not find module 'hdf5.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I thought this error was caused due to improper installation of h5py & hdf5. I tried installing them using `pip install h5py` but then I encountered the following error:

```
(keras) C:\Users\namba>pip install h5py
Collecting h5py
  Using cached h5py-3.1.0.tar.gz (371 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.5; python_version == "3.8" in c:\users\namba\keras\lib\site-packages (from h5py) (1.19.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
  Building wheel for h5py (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\namba\keras\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\namba\keras\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\namba\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpid2mdza_'
       cwd: C:\Users\namba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yppxk_bm\h5py
  Complete output (70 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\h5py_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\ipy_completer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\dims.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\files.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\selections2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attribute_create.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attrs_data.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_big_endian_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_completions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_getitem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_swmr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dimension_scales.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dtype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file_image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5f.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5p.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5pl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5t.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_objects.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_slicing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_highlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_virtual_source.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  running build_ext
  Loading library to get version: hdf5.dll
  error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly
  error: Could not find module 'hdf5.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Please suggest any solutions to overcome these errors?

Comment: This error ```error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly``` might be the solution to the problem. Have you tried installing hdf5 before installing h5py? Your HDF5 installation might be the problem - lack thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it happens due to old version of `pip`

upgrade pip:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

then try again:

```
pip install h5py
```

Note: make sure your python3.8 is 64bit

Comment: I am using pip(20.2.4), and I tried installing h5py. But still, I am encountering the same error.

Comment: which version of python you are using?

Comment: I am using python 3.8

Comment: you need python3.8 64 bit. is your python3.8 64 bit?

Comment: Thank you!!! I've installed python 3.8.6 64bit and it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

It is preferred to use a 64bit python3(<3.9), to work with deep learning libraries(Keras, TensorFlow), because testings on 32bit were not yet performed and released. So, Make sure you check whether it is 64 bit or 32 bit. Thanks to [Tasnuva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8237683/tasnuva) for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The following is the procedure I followed to fix the problem.
First, to check which version you're using:

- look at the bottom left corner of Visual Studio Code in case you're using this IDE (you'll find something like `Python v.v.v 32-bit`)
- execute `python -VV` from the terminal
  Then download and install the 64-bit version of python from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) (don't forget to check *Add Python v.v to PATH* before installing)
  Delete the existing virtual environment (if you already have one) and create a new venv with the latest version of Python that you downloaded.